# Can I bring hair treatment products and shampoo/conditioner over 100ml in my checked luggage?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airports

Okay so I'm sorry if it's a dumb question but I've never been in a plane before and I'm LOST. I just wonder if I can take my treatment hair products and my shampoo/conditioner OVER 100ml in my checked luggage or if I can only take 100ml each...

Comment: Pack them in a ziplock bag still, not because of any rules but because the more you have the worse a leak of during travels is.

Comment: The answers here are generally correct, but there are some restrictions on liquids, even in checked luggage. For instance, the TSA prohibits any bottles over 17 oz, and I think there’s limits on the total amount you can bring. Just be sure to check their website before you go!

Comment: Ask your travel agent or other ticket vendor, and tell them their answer is of the essence in your contract…

Comment: "TSA prohibits any bottles over 17 oz" - so you can't even bring a single wine bottle to the US?

Comment: No, that limit applies only to non-food items like toiletries or medicines

Answer (score 16):

In the days of the 100ml rule I have yet to take a flight without more than 100ml of shampoo and 100ml of conditioner in a checked bag.  It's a complete non-issue, the liquid rules do not apply to checked baggage, only to carry-on.

Comment: Oh thank god lol i was worried I'd have to spent 14 days without treating my hair LMAO

Comment: @Ghostie The only thing people will typically be carrying that can't be checked is lithium-ion batteries.  Beyond that, many things associated with fire are prohibited but most people aren't carrying them, anyway.

Comment: @Ghostie Do they not have Walgreens / CVS / Tesco / Albert Heijn / similar stores where you are going?

Comment: @shoover I was considering that, also, but that means leaving behind partial bottles when you return.

Comment: @Ghostie Why does it mean leaving behind partial bottles? You can just put them in your checked luggage

Comment: @Traveller not if they cannot take them to their destination in the first place (that was the point of the question)

Comment: @Chieron My comment was in response to an earlier comment about the availability of hair care products in the OP’s destination

Answer (score 8):

There is no volume limit for liquids within checked-luggage. It is very common for people to carry liquid cosmetic products since carry-on restrictions very tight. Of course, the total weight of the suitcase has a limit but for a few bottles of shampoo, conditioner, etc you should be able to be within the limit.

More important than the volume is the *type* of container. Simple plastic bottles or even ones with a spray nozzle are fine but pressurized products are categorized as *hazardous material*. Aerosols for toiletries are not allowed in large quantities but they may be allowed in small sizes. The FAA specifies a limit but lets airlines add further restrictions and there are different rules outside of the US.

The [FAA has a very informative page](https://www.faa.gov/hazmat/packsafe/) on the matter for more detail. You did not mention where you will be flying, so if it is outside of the USA, other rules apply for aerosols. For simple plastic or glass bottles that contain shampoo, conditioners, sunscreen, etc, then you can have them in checked luggage.

Comment: Correct - but I have many times brought 15 - 20 deodorant spray bottles in my luggage, never any issues. “Large amounts” seem to start at much more.

Comment: @Aganju Okay, I have to ask why you are carrying 15-20 deodorant spray bottles with any frequency ...

Comment: My favorite one is not sold in the country I live - so I bring it when I do business trips, every year.